# MySQL Community Server 8 doesn`t want to start

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, innodb

After I updated the mysql server to version 8.0.3 it wouldn`t start any more. The error.log gives me

> 2018-10-30T19:11:59.014423Z 1 [ERROR] InnoDB: Unsupported redo log format. The redo log was created before MySQL 5.7.9.
>   2018-10-30T19:11:59.014489Z 1 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
>   2018-10-30T19:11:59.615108Z 1 [ERROR] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
>   2018-10-30T19:11:59.615582Z 0 [ERROR] Data Dictionary initialization failed.

It is not important to fix the mysql server (it would be nice), but I need the data out of the database, but I cannot read the ibdata1 file from /var/lib/mysql.

my server runs on Linux Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS

Please help me!

Jonas

Answer (score 1):

If you are upgrading from pre-5.7.9, you *must* first upgrade to 5.7, then go to 8.0.

At each stage, you must run `mysql_upgrade`.

There is no turning back from 8.0.

Note that 8.0.3 is pre-GA.  Please don't consider moving to it; move to a GA version (8.0.11 or later).